# Magento get category url from ID without ?SID=

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

In Magento I have this to get the the url of a category from its ID

```
$categoryLink = Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load(10)->getUrl();
```

It works but at the end of url there is `?SID=somenumber`.

I know I could remove it from

System > Configuration > Web > Session Validation Settings > Use SID on Frontend

But I want to keep it active, so how can i get the url of category without the `?SID=somenumber`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$categoryLink = Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load(10)->getUrl();
$pos = strpos($categoryLink, '?');
$categoryLink = ($pos>0) ? substr($categoryLink, 0, $pos) : $categoryLink;
```

Answer (score 6):

```
    $params = array(
        '_nosid' => true
    );

    $url = Mage::getUrl('*/*/*', $params);
```

Comment: This is the right answer. In a template you can also use it, for example:
`$this->getUrl('blog/tag/amazing/', ['_nosid' => true])`

Comment: this is best answer dont know why other answer is accepted

Answer (score 1):

You can configure this from admin panel :

**Go to** `Admin == System == Configuration == Web == Session Validation Settings` and `disable` config `Use SID on Frontend = No`

Comment: Thank you for your help, but like I wrote I knew this solution, but i need to keep it active! Do you have other suggest?